# BCryptPasswordEncoder not imported as part of spring-boot-starter-security

Tags: spring-boot, password-encryption, password-hash

Can't find bean BCryptPasswordEncoder although I imported it through maven dependency and spring-boot-starter-security

I tried to use BCryptPasswordEncoder for password hashing, but when I started project I got error:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in
>   com.websystique.springboot.controller.RestApiController required a
>   bean of type
>   'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder'
>   that could not be found.

I am using spring-boot, and I just used it in my controller like:

`@Autowired BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;`

Answer (score 2):

Add BcryptPasswordEncoder bean in your `@Configuration` class. It does not be declared automaically.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

(Optional) And inject like this.

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```